# FOUC How to remove "Flash Of Unstyled Content" in Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js, fouc

As I was testing my Nuxt application, I purposely entered page URLs that I know didn't exist to test my 404 page; I then saw a flash of a completely white screen before the page navigated to my 404 page.

How do you get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are looking for the answer, here's a solution:

In your nuxt.config.js file, add this:

```js
css: ['@/assets/whatever_you_want_to_name_this_file.css'],
```

Then create the whatever_you_want_to_name_this_file.css in your assets folder.

Next add the following code to the whatever_you_want_to_name_this_file.css:

```css
#__nuxt,
body,
html {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

I was using a dark theme using Vuetify; so I set the background color to black but you could set it to whatever you want.

Comment: So this will make the background black and not fix the flash..

Comment: So add an opacity of 0 then and set it back to 1 once you have everything loaded:

#__nuxt,
body,
html {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 0;
}

Comment: You're basically just performing some perceptual trickery.

Comment: BTW a lot of people use the GSAP library to slowly fade up the background stuff so that it smoothly transitions in.https://greensock.com/fouc/